# How to deploy a mulitplayer game with socket.io from localhost to Online server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, ecmascript-6, socket.io

I can make Javascript programs, but I knew nothing about servers.
I started learning to create a multiplayer game with socket.io from this tutorail.

- [server side tutorial](https://gamedevacademy.org/create-a-basic-multiplayer-game-in-phaser-3-with-socket-io-part-1/)
- [client side tutorial](https://gamedevacademy.org/create-a-basic-multiplayer-game-in-phaser-3-with-socket-io-part-2/)

On this basis of the tutorial I created a game with localhost but I do not know, how to deploy this server online. So that multiplayers from different platforms/computers/mobiles can play online with each other.

How can I move from localhost to online?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

var players = {};

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('a user connected');
  // create a new player and add it to our players object
  players[socket.id] = {
    rotation: 0,
    x: Math.floor(Math.random() * 700) + 50,
    y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 50,
    playerId: socket.id,
    team: (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0) ? 'red' : 'blue'
  };
  // send the players object to the new player
  socket.emit('currentPlayers', players);
  // update all other players of the new player
  socket.broadcast.emit('newPlayer', players[socket.id]);

  // when a player disconnects, remove them from our players object
  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('user disconnected');
    // remove this player from our players object
    delete players[socket.id];
    // emit a message to all players to remove this player
    io.emit('disconnect', socket.id);
  });
});

server.listen(8081, function () {
  console.log(`Listening on ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

Comment: Hi @Harry, there is tons of ways to deploy an application to online, what your server config like, which type of stuff using to serve your app?

Comment: Aight so u just need to deploy this to a server. Man it's really lot's of choices there, buy a heroku account and deploy it here, build your own server. its just a matter of choice and research, https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git is one artikel from heroku, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04 another from digitalocean so you just need to pick one and go for it

Comment: I am using phaser js on the client side just like the tutorials above. The player performs an action, sends an abject with a event. Server receives, updates the information and passes the information to other clients. Other clients use the information and display on the client screen with the help of phaser framework. I want to create android application through phonegap for play store which will help the players to play with each other.

Comment: I don't know what changes I have to make in my code, after chosing one from the options given by you.

Comment: Basicly nothing probably, 'http' to 'https' for creating server and also gave some certificate info, it's also gonna change by the way you wanna go with. Does this version of your code works fine on local right now?

Comment: Yeah!  It works perfectly with the localhost.

Comment: Aight then and are you serving files from express?

Comment: Yes. I am using express.

Comment: Aight so i believe you might just check heroku's deployment options, and follow their intro to deploy a nodejs app to server.

Comment: `var server = require('https').Server(certificateOptions, app);` probably you are gonna change this when deploying app to server cause u cant http connection to a https served file

Comment: OK. I will try and learn from there. Thanks a lot. Will come back here after i do this.

Comment: Sure send us link so we can play too .

Comment: Definitely. ☺  thanks

Comment: Note that heroku cycle all dynos every 24 hours, which means some players will get disconnected. I am experiencing this exact same issue in my game. Looking for another place to deploy my game at.